# Plotting data from serial port

Tags: python, csv, serial-port, matplotlib, save

I have a Python script which reads data from a serial port and then writes the data to a CSV file. I then have another Python script which plots the data from the CSV file using matplotlib and saves it as an image.

How can I have my first script plot simultaneously while reading from the serial port? In other words, how can I plot the data read from serial port without using an intermediate CSV file?

Comment: I would stick to the animation answer, but I didn't got your question. Do you have some issues with the animation or something else, like you don't know how to plot the serial port data?

Comment: i could plot a csv file. but not able to plot when data is being read.

Comment: Okay. I think now I know, what you want. May [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797249/microprocessor-to-rs-232-realtime-plot-using-pyserial-matplotlib) could help you. It's difficult to answer you question, cause I don't know how you get your serial data and so on.